# Cannot send messages in production (elastic beanstalk)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I cannot get my applications sending messages in productions in AWS's Elastic Beanstalk. I have my application working in dev. When I transfer to production in elastic beanstalk I get an issue sending messages.

```
[HTTP 404] 20404 : Unable to create record The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Messages.json was not found https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404
```

I think I have the secrets.yml file setup correctly. Below is a redacted version.

```
development:
  secret_key_base: asdfff
  twilio_account_sid:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>
  twilio_auth_token:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>
  twilio_phone_number:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>

test:
  secret_key_base: asdfff
  twilio_account_sid:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>
  twilio_auth_token:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>
  twilio_phone_number:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>

production:
  secret_key_base: asdfff
  twilio_account_sid:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>
  twilio_auth_token:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>
  twilio_phone_number:  <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE", "asdf") %>
```

I have also run this command to update my secrets.

```
eb setenv SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(rails secret)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Silly question, but did you look at the example issues on the page it references? https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404

Comment: @WillMavis Of course, that's not helping at all. It's some combination of running in production, using elastic beanstalk, and twilio at the same time.

Comment: When it is working in development, does it log the resources it is accessing (something like "The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Messages.json")?  If so, does comparing those resources give any indication to what's different about production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It appears you have your secrets.yml file setting everything to your Rails application secret key base. It should probably look more like:

```
 production:
  secret_key_base: asdfff
  twilio_account_sid:  <%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID", "asdf") %>
  twilio_auth_token:  <%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN", "asdf") %>
  twilio_phone_number:  <%= ENV.fetch("TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER", "asdf") %>
```

You should then get those three other environment variables from your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console) and set them using the same command:

```
eb setenv TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=ACXXXXXXXXX TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=YYYYYYYYYYY TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER=+15551234567
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I would suggest that this guide be updated to remove the SECRET_KEY_BASE references in regards to the twilio configuration. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/send-sms-ruby-rails-5-coffee.html

Comment: Ah, thanks. That is an odd way to place the env variables in that blog post. I'll see about updating it.